# overload of template template function - explicit call

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

So, first consider the following where template parameters are known implicitly from the function arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {};
class B {};

template <class T1, class T2>
class C { 
    T1 a; 
    T2 b; 
};

template <class T1>
class D {
    T1 a;
};

template <template<class, class> class TC, class TA, class TB>
void foo(TC<TA, TB> c) {
    std::cout << "T<T,T>" << std::endl;
};

template <template<class> class TD, class TA>
void foo(TD<TA> d){
    std::cout << "T<T>" << std::endl;
};

int main() {
    C<A,B> c;
    D<A> d;

    foo(c);
    foo(d);
}
```

And output is as you'd expect:

```
T<T,T>
T<T>
```

However, what if I don't have an instance of class `C` and `D` so I need to explicitly call the correct overload?  How would this be done?  i.e., have a `main()` that consists of:

```
int main() {
    foo<C<A,B> >();
    foo<D<A> >();
}
```

I've experimented with a few overloads of `foo()` as shown below:

```
template <template<class, class> class TC>
void foo() {
    std::cout << "T<T,T>" << std::endl;
};

template <template<class> class TD>
void foo(){
    std::cout << "T<T>" << std::endl;
};

template <template<class, class> class TC, class TA, class TB>
void foo() {
    std::cout << "T<T,T>" << std::endl;
};

template <template<class> class TD, class TA>
void foo(){
    std::cout << "T<T>" << std::endl;
};
```

However, this (and all permutations I've been able to think of) simply results in a series of errors along the lines of the (abbreviated) output shown below

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:44:18: error: no matching function for call to 'foo()'
     foo<C<A,B> >();
                  ^
prog.cpp:44:18: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:19:6: note: template<template<class, class> class TC> void foo()
 void foo() {
      ^
prog.cpp:19:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:24:6: note: template<template<class> class TD> void foo()
 void foo(){
      ^
prog.cpp:24:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Is what I'm looking to do even allowable?  If so, where am I messing up?

**---- EDIT ----**

So as apple apple pointed out if my `main()` is as follows:

```
int main() {
    foo<C, A, B>();
    foo<D, A>();
}
```

I get the output as expected.

However, my real-world case winds up being more complex.  I'll expand a bit here.  The legacy code has (hundreds) of typedefs defined in headers elsewhere along the lines of:

```
typedef C<A, B> type_117;
typedef D<A>    type_252;
```

The class I'm working on is templated and is instantiated with one of those typedefs as the templating argument.  So something along the lines of:

```
template <class Type>
class Test
{
public:
   Test();
   SomeClass mSC;
}
Test::Test()
  : mSC(foo<Type>())
{
};
```

where Test was instantiated as

```
Test<type_117> aTest;
```

So I've been trying to figure out how to write `foo()` for this context.  At the point I call `foo()` within my `Test`'s initializer am I able to "decompose" it to produce the `<C,A,B>` form?  Or have I hit a roadblock and need to rework some of the existing framework?

Comment: isn't it `foo<C,A,B>();` ?

Comment: that does appear to work... leads to a followup question though -- I'll edit the original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){}};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
```

these are type tags.  They can be passed to functions without an instance of the type.

Template functions will deduce on them.

```
template <template<class, class> class TC, class TA, class TB>
void foo(tag_t<TC<TA, TB>>) {
  std::cout << "T<T,T>" << std::endl;
};

template <template<class> class TD, class TA>
void foo(tag_t<TD<TA>>){
  std::cout << "T<T>" << std::endl;
};
```

at call site do `foo(tag<type_117>)` and bob, as they say, is your uncle.

In C++98 (ick):

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{};
foo(tag_t<type_117>());
```

Comment: That looks fascinating, but also looks like it only works with c++11 and the use of constexpr can't be avoied.  My fault for not stating that I'm not able to (yet) transition to new features.  Will def keep in mind for future efforts though!

Comment: @Khanmots No, it doesn't need `constexpr`; drop it from the type.  The template variable `tag` is optional, simply replace use with `tag_t<type_117>()`.  In practice, consider using a C++ standard more recent than 19 years ago.  ;)  Edited into answer.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  And large organization with a large legacy codebase is slow to change... been trying :)

Answer (score 2):

Take in count that partial specialization is forbidden for functions; so is difficult to do what do you exactly asked.

The suggestion from apple apple (chenge the calling as `foo<C, A, B>()` is a good one but, if you want to maintain the original call (`foo<C<A, B>>()`) you can use the fact that the partial specialization is allowed for structs/classes and create a partial specialization for a functor; something like

```
template <typename>
struct bar;

template <template<typename, typename> class Tc, typename Ta, typename Tb>
struct bar<Tc<Ta,Tb>>
 {
   void operator() ()
    { std::cout << "bar<Tc<Ta, Tb>>()" << std::endl; }
 };

template <template<typename> class Tc, typename Ta>
struct bar<Tc<Ta>>
 {
   void operator() ()
    { std::cout << "bar<Tc<Ta>>()" << std::endl; }
 };
```

The problem (?) is that, calling it, you can't call as `bar<C<A,B>>()` od `bar<D<A>>()` but you have to add a couple of parentheses:

```
bar<C<A,B>>()();
bar<D<A>>()();
```

or

```
bar<C<A,B>>{}();
bar<D<A>>{}();
```

I suppose that the functor solution can solve also the problem of the Edit part of your question.

If the added couple of parentheses is a problem, you can (as suggested by Jarod42 (thanks!)) wrap the call in a template function, as follows

```
template <typename T>
void bar ()
 { bar<T>{}(); }
```

So you can call the `bar<C<A, B>>()` function and manage the call in the specialized `bar<C<A, B>>` struct.

Observe also the solution from Jarod42: depending on your requirements, you could develop only a version of the partial specialization of `bar`.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> I'm not that familiar with partial specialization; could you expand a bit on how what I was trying was?

Specialization (partial and full) is a big, big topic.

Just some example, to give an idea.

Given a template class/struct

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
struct foo
 { };
```

you can *partial* specialize it as follows (by example)

```
template <typename X>
struct foo<X, X>
 { };
```

when the specialization maintain a template variable, or you can *full* specialize as follow (by example)

```
template <>
struct foo<int, long>
 { };
```

where all template argument are fixed.

Well: with function you can full specialize but not partial specialize.

So you can write a template function

```
 template <typename X, template Y>
 void foo ()
  { }
```

and full specialize it

```
 template <>
 void foo<int, long> ()
  { }
```

but you can't partial specialize it; so you can't write (is an error)

```
 template <typename X>
 void foo<X, X> ()
  { }
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with partial specialization; could you expand a bit on how what I was trying was?

Comment: And functors are a good idea, that may well be the route I take.

Comment: To bypass the "problem", you may add `template <typename T> void bar2() { bar<T>{}(); }` and call `bar2` instead of `bar`.

Comment: I would avoid naming the wrapper `foo`, as OP use also `foo`. `detail_bar`and `bar` would be better names.

Comment: @Jarod42 - OK; `bar()`.

Comment: @Khanmots - answer improved with a suggestion from Jarod42 and a little explanation about specialization.

Comment: So template `<template<class> class TD> void foo()` counts as a partial specialization of `template <template<class, class> class TC> void foo()` ?

Comment: @Khanmots - no; they are two different templates funtions; no specialized; they have a template-template argument that is a particular type of template argument (others are typename and value template arguments).

Comment: That's what I had thought... so I'm still not seeing the partial specialization.  I've tried with just those two foo() definitions mentioned and gotten the same result.  I can make a different question if you need?

Comment: @Khanmots - this topic (partial/full specialization) is really important in modern c++; I was hoping that my little examples can help you but, at this point, I suggest you to look for a good book or a good tutorial

Comment: Will do.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may use partial specialization (and variadic template):

```
template <class Type>
class Test;

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename ... Ts>
class Test<C<Ts...>>
{
public:
   Test() : mSC(foo<C, Ts...>()) {}
   SomeClass mSC;
};
```